# Force close when press back while fetching data from internet

Tags: android

Whenever user press back  button While fetching xml data from web using AsyncTask my app goes to force close state. How can i solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
public class InboxActivity extends Activity {
public static ExpandableListView mailList;
List<HashMap<String,String>> list;
MailList asyncTaskMailList;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inbox_layout);
    ConstantValues.footerCurrentActivity=InboxActivity.this;
    mailList=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
    HomePageActivity.homePageTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(ConstantValues.CURRENT_POSITION)
        .setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_widget_normal));
    asyncTaskMailList=new MailList();
    asyncTaskMailList.execute();
}
private OnChildClickListener childClickListener=new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        ConstantValues.STATION_NAME=ConstantValues.inboxStations.get(groupPosition);
        ConstantValues.CURRENT_POSITION=1;
        startActivity(new Intent(InboxActivity.this, HomePageActivity.class));
        return false;
    }
};
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        this.getParent().onBackPressed();
        asyncTaskMailList.cancel(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    asyncTaskMailList.cancel(true);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    asyncTaskMailList.cancel(true);
    super.onDestroy();
}
class MailList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        NetworkExceptionPopUp.showProgressBar();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        WebServerCall.getInboxMail(InboxActivity.this);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mailList.setAdapter(new InboxAdapter(InboxActivity.this));
        NetworkExceptionPopUp.dismissProgressBar();
        mailList.setOnGroupClickListener(null);
        mailList.setOnChildClickListener(childClickListener);
        mailList.setClickable(true);

    }
}
```

}
    Above code is my updated code. This also sometime shows exception. Here, I had used onStop() and OnDestroy() to cancel AsyncTask while other activity comes top.

Comment: Can you check logcat and see if there's a stack trace?

Comment: It could be the code in the onPostExecute. You are accessing a lot of UI elements which doesn't exist since the user pressed back.

Comment: Yes, I got some errors in my logcat.

Comment: @Premsuraj Sorry, I can't understand what your are trying to say Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        NetworkExceptionPopUp.showProgressBar(); 
       /** add this line to your progressDialog so that diaolg as well your background operation wont stop in intermediate state. */
        // pd.setCancelable(false);
    }
```

So now when you will click back button  Dialog will not dismiss.

Hope this help for you.

Comment: Yes you are correct but i don't want to keep user to wait that much time. Please give some other ideas. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
private MailList task; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    task = new MailList().execute();
    ...
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (task != null && task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
        task.cancel(true);
    }
    ...
}

...
```

Comment: @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
      this.getParent().onBackPressed();
      new MailList().cancel(true);
         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

Comment: @SathishKumar you can't use new MailList.cancel(true), you need to keep a member variable of your task, like belyjz pointed out, task = new MailList().execute,. Then call cacel(true) on the 'task' variable

Comment: It is working sometime only sometime throws exception how to fix it.Thank You.